# Search in solr for Chinese not returning result for bigger words

Tags: indexing, solr, lucene, sitecore, cjk

I'm trying to configure SOLR to search in Chinese but I have problem with quality of result that are coming back. In my scheme I declared fieldType for chinese like that:

```
<fieldType name="text_general_zh" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer class="org.apache.lucene.analysis.cjk.CJKAnalyzer" words="lang/stopwords_zh.txt"/>
</fieldType>
```

Also I tried:

```
<analyzer>
    <tokenizer class="solr.HMMChineseTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
      words="org/apache/lucene/analysis/cn/smart/stopwords.txt"/>
    <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
</analyzer>
```

And custom field:

```
<field name="namesearch_t_th" type="text_general_th" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

I have document in index with value for that field:

"namesearch_t_th":"新代理 - 模塊"

Problem is when I want to search with 3 Chinese charatcter or more. SOLR doesn't return any result. It work when I give only two or one character. Do you have any idea how to make it working with more than 2 characters?

Not working query:

```
contentnamesearch_t_zh:(新代理*)
```

There are working:

```
contentnamesearch_t_zh:(新代*)
contentnamesearch_t_zh:(代理*)
```

Comment: How did you fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a wildcard is present, the analysis chain isn't run. Since you have a tokenizer defined, my guess is that these words (my Chinese isn't that good) are stored as separate tokens. Since you have a wildcard, the tokenizer (or any of the other filters, unless they're MultitermAware) isn't invoked, and 新代理* doesn't match any single tokens.

You can solve this by having a field that isn't processed and match against that. Use a copyField instruction to index the same content into multiple fields with different processing instructions, and search against the field that hasn't been tokenized or processed.